# asp.net error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Sorry, but this is a brain phart. I have searched the whole internet, but can't figure this out.
**Error:**  *"Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'."*

```
if (oDbDataReader.GetString(2) == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90).ToShortDateString())       //DateCreated
{
    oEmp.PasswordCompliance = "Password expired";
}
```

Comment: Remove the semi-colon at the end of your `if` condition

Comment: Instead of using .AddDays(-90), you can do: DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(90))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems, first you are comparing for equality, if anyone checks after 3 months this will not trigger. Second, you probably are storing a `Date` or `DateTime` in you database, causing your call to `GetString` to fail.

Use the following instead (no reason to do use strings in this case).

```
if (oDbDataReader.GetDateTime(2) <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90))
```

Also note that your original had an extra `;` potentially causing your password to always be expired.

Answer (score 4):

What is the type of the column [2]? If it is `DateTime` you should try [DbDataReader.GetDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getdatetime.aspx)

```
if (oDbDataReader.GetDateTime(2) < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90)) 
{
    oEmp.PasswordCompliance = "Password expired";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value in the column at position 2 in the reader is a DateTime, not a string. So the GetString call fails.